# Как разместить текст на html так, чтобы он подстроился при изменении разрешения экрана

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox, адаптивная-верстка

Проблема, которую я никак не могу решить - что же нужно изменить в моём коде для того, чтобы при изменении разрешения экрана, текст помещался по центру.

Буду очень рад помощи.

Мой код:

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  background: grey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0.5rem 5rem;
  position: fixed;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="left: 0px;">
    <a href="home_page.html" , target="_self">Текст1</a>
  </li>
  <li style="left: 320px;">
    <a href="about.html" , target="_self">Текст2</a>
  </li>
  <li style="left: 640px;">
    <a href="service.html" , target="_self">Текст3</a>
  </li>
  <li style="left: 960px;">
    <a href="contakt.html" , target="_self">Текст4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал так, как понял ваш вопрос. Если что не так, пишите, поправим.

```css
ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  background: grey;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0.5rem 5rem;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="home_page.html">Текст1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="about.html">Текст2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="service.html">Текст3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="contakt.html">Текст4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я бы советовал подключить normalize что бы муторно не убирать дефолтные приколы браузеров.
[Подключаем](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/modern-normalize)

Я добавил обёртку для списка. Относительно чего оно должно центрироваться?
Так же центрирование flex'ом прям супер удобная штука, рекомендую ознакомиться
[Читаем](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
.test {
    width: 1920px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    background: grey;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li {
    font-size: 200%;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24),
        0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
 <div class="test">
            <ul>
                <li style="left: 0px">
                    <a href="home_page.html" , target="_self">Текст1</a>
                </li>
                <li style="left: 320px">
                    <a href="about.html" , target="_self">Текст2</a>
                </li>
                <li style="left: 640px">
                    <a href="service.html" , target="_self">Текст3</a>
                </li>
                <li style="left: 960px">
                    <a href="contakt.html" , target="_self">Текст4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```